# Magento translation text in php

Tags: magento

I have a public function in Magento that contain text `"All Categories"`, how I can translate this text in Magento. For example I want to be translated in the `Mage_Catalog.csv` file

```
public function getCatNameCustom($category){
    $level = $category->getLevel();
    $html = '';
    for($i = 0;$i < $level;$i++){
        $html .= '';
    }
    if($level == 1) return $html.' '.$this->__("All Categories");
    else return $html.' '.$category->getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your method is in the module **Mage_Catalog**, then it can be translated in **Mage_Catalog.csv**.

If your method is for example in the module **CustomDeveloper_CustomModule**, then module needs to define it's translation file in **config.xml** and then you can put your translation inside **CustomDeveloper_CustomModule.csv** (if it is defined like that in xml file).